# Adding additional text under the price via product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, widgets

Hey guys I am wanting to just add this additional text underneath the price (circled in red)
I am using Xstore child theme via woocommerce/WP and have no idea how to go about adding this in or which option would be easiest?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this may not be what you want, but i would make the product a variable product, and have the per pack available for purchase, if that's what you want. otherwise if it will be dynamic and a different price for all products, you may need to do some custom coding for it. or possibly place it in the short description and use [hooks](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/)
to change the position of the short description